# Wget/bash downloading certain DIV

Tags: wget

I  just came across this problem and my little knowledge in programming is killing me right now ;) So, i have a certain gallery on a image sharing website this is ImageBam, i have never downloaded images from this website.

right now I am using this code:

```
wget -P pics -H -nd -r -A '.jpg,.jpeg,.png,.gif,' -erobots=off http://www.imagebam.com/gallery/hwtfu6m7es3gun1emmpy2uheohrcckmt/
```

This code is downloading the whole website, when i only need to download content from a certain DIV, that includes thumbnails and original image.

Do you know if its possible to create a script in bash or any other language to download content from one div and not the whole webiste and all the possible hyperlinks ?

thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

[Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) would be a good option.

Answer (score 0):

`wget` is not meant to parse files, only download them.

What you want is [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) which is like wget, but with the added ability to parse files for the desired target.

Comment: cool, thanks for that, but how can I make it download images and thumbnails ?

Comment: Hmm, I think I am thinking of cURL in the context of PHP. In that case, you would use XPath to denote the target DIV. I’m guessing that you are not looking to do any programming, so I’ll check for a simpler option…